# From Kb validation to mb Laravel change message

Tags: laravel

Hi there can someone help me with this:

```
'max'       => [
        'file'    => 'The :attribute may not be greater than :max kilobytes.',
       ],
```

And my message is this:

```
The image may not be greater than 2048 kilobytes.
```

I need it to be like this:

```
The question image may not be greater than 2 mb.
```

Is there a way to do this ..? Please help..!

Comment: Please follow this link may i help you (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414278/how-to-change-laravel-validation-message-for-max-file-size-in-mb-instead-of-kb)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414278/how-to-change-laravel-validation-message-for-max-file-size-in-mb-instead-of-kb

Comment: I tried that but does not work it gave me Call to undefined method [requireParameterCount]

Comment: Are you using an inline validation? or a separate FormRequest class?

Comment: I dont understand exactly what are you saying sorry, but I have image, audio, and video and image needs to be up to 2mb, audio 3mb and video 10mb so I think seperate..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most straightforward way to override your error message is by using the `messages()` method of `FormRequest` class.

```
class UploadFileRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'image' => "file|max:2048",
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get custom messages for validator errors.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'image.max' => "The question image may not be greater than 2 mb.",
        ];
    }
}
```